# str_remove() in R - Dealing With Special Characters

Tags: r, string, stringr

I ran this line of code:

```
str_remove("abc(d)efg", "abc")
```

and it gave me what I wanted:

```
[1] "(d)efg"
```

However when I ran:

```
str_remove("abc(d)efg", "abc(d)")
```

I hoped I would see

```
[1] "efg"
```

but instead I saw

```
[1] "abc(d)efg"
```

Are the `(` and the `)` treated somehow as special characters inside the `str_remove()` call?

Thank you.

Comment: you need to escape them `\\(`

Answer (score 3):

Use `fixed` as wrappers as the `()` are metacharacters and by default it is in regex mode i.e. `()` will assume that we are capturing characters within

```
library(stringr)
str_remove("abc(d)efg", fixed("abc(d)"))
[1] "efg"
```